# breaking transitive dependencies in third normal form (case)

Tags: database-normalization, third-normal-form

Suppose we are second normal form with:

```
R(a,b,c,d,e)
FD: (a->bcde, c->de, d->e)
```

And we remove transitive dependencies:

```
R1(a,b,c)
R2(c,d,e)
R3(d,e)
```

Is this a correct decomposition?

Comment: To form a correct decomposition, the second relation shoul be `R2(c,d)`.

Comment: @Renzo So R1(a,b,c), R2(c,d) and R3(d,e) is correct form of decomposition?

Comment: Yes. It is a decomposition that preserves data and dependencies, and the produced relations are in Boyce-Codd Normal Form, which is a normal form stronger than the Third Normal Form.